# __autoload() is deprecated, use spl_autoload_register() instead in app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 61

Tags: magento1.9.3, php-7.3

In Magento 1.9.3.x..we have upgrade php version from 5.6 to 7.3.after that we are facing issue like

Deprecated: __autoload() is deprecated, use spl_autoload_register() instead in app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 61 . function look like below

function __autoload($class)
{

```
if (defined('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    $classFile = $class.'.php';
} else {
    $classFile = uc_words($class, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR).'.php';
}

include($classFile);
```

}

we have replace with

function spl_autoload_register($class)
{

```
if (defined('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    $classFile = $class.'.php';
} else {
    $classFile = uc_words($class, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR).'.php';
}

include($classFile);
```

}

But again it throws an fetal error like
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare spl_autoload_register() in app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 71

Please help me...my live site is not working because of this upgradation..

Answer (score 0):

"Deprecated" means removed in a further version or shouldn't be used in favor of another method. So no, these mehtods have not to be removed yet.

You can try this in index.php to supress errors:

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);